# How to resolve issue with building stream-fusion

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to bring in the stream-fusion library into my project. I am using Stack (LTS 5.16). I added the stream-fusion-0.1.2.5 version to my project's cabal file and also as an extra-dependency in my stack.yaml.

However, when I try to build the project I now get the following:

```
stream-fusion-0.1.2.5: configure
stream-fusion-0.1.2.5: build

--  While building package stream-fusion-0.1.2.5 using:
      /Users/me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/me/Haskell/hqfl/.stack-work/logs/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5.log

    Configuring stream-fusion-0.1.2.5...
    Building stream-fusion-0.1.2.5...
    Preprocessing library stream-fusion-0.1.2.5...
    [1 of 3] Compiling Data.Stream      ( Data/Stream.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/Stream.o )

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/Stream.hs:591:5: Warning:
        Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
        In an equation for ‘next’:
            Patterns not matched: (_ :!: (Just (L _))) :!: S2
    [2 of 3] Compiling Data.List.Stream ( Data/List/Stream.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Data/List/Stream.o )

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/List/Stream.hs:235:1: Warning:
        The import of ‘seq, Int’ from module ‘Prelude’ is redundant

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/List/Stream.hs:1703:10: Warning: Tab character

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/List/Stream.hs:2496:1: Warning:
        Rule "genericSplitAt -> fusible" may never fire
          because ‘genericSplitAt’ might inline first
        Probable fix: add an INLINE[n] or NOINLINE[n] pragma on ‘genericSplitAt’

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/List/Stream.hs:2504:1: Warning:
        Rule "genericSplitAt -> splitAt/Int" may never fire
          because ‘genericSplitAt’ might inline first
        Probable fix: add an INLINE[n] or NOINLINE[n] pragma on ‘genericSplitAt’

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Data/List/Stream.hs:2516:1: Warning:
        Rule "genericReplicate -> replicate/Int" may never fire
          because ‘genericReplicate’ might inline first
        Probable fix: add an INLINE[n] or NOINLINE[n] pragma on ‘genericReplicate’
    [3 of 3] Compiling Control.Monad.Stream ( Control/Monad/Stream.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Control/Monad/Stream.o )

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Control/Monad/Stream.hs:136:10:
        Ambiguous occurrence ‘MonadPlus’
        It could refer to either ‘Control.Monad.Stream.MonadPlus’,
                                 defined at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:124:1
                              or ‘GHC.Base.MonadPlus’,
                                 imported from ‘GHC.Base’ at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:80:1-15

    /private/var/folders/q_/qbq9bct96jj8p_c9kqbhmt840000gn/T/stack6002/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/Control/Monad/Stream.hs:140:10:
        Ambiguous occurrence ‘MonadPlus’
        It could refer to either ‘Control.Monad.Stream.MonadPlus’,
                                 defined at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:124:1
                              or ‘GHC.Base.MonadPlus’,
                                 imported from ‘GHC.Base’ at Control/Monad/Stream.hs:80:1-15
```

How can I resolve the ambiguity here?

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the following imports in `Control.Monad.Stream` (line 80)

```
- import GHC.Base
+ import           GHC.Base hiding ( MonadPlus
+                                 , (=<<)
+                                 , ap
+                                 , join
+                                 , liftM
+                                 , liftM2
+                                 , liftM3
+                                 , liftM4
+                                 , liftM5
+                                 , mapM
+                                 , mplus
+                                 , mzero
+                                 , sequence
+                                 , when
+                                 )
```

Then it compiles - I don't know wether it will work as expected, this library is quite old (3 years as of now) and the *tested-with* section in the cabal file says 7.6.1. - I recommend using benchmarks to ensure that the benefits you hope to get from this library are real. I would guess that a lot of the ideas of this library have made it into base by now.

Could you leave a comment after you have done these benchmarks I would really be interested in them.

Comment: I was wondering about that and moved the /test/Bench directory to /Bench and made it a cabal bench. These are the results http://lpaste.net/163848 The first figure is Data.List, the second Data.List.Stream.  GHC doesn't use any of this, it just improved its own build/foldr machinery, I think.

Comment: I put your emendation plus the cabalized bench up here git@gitlab.com:michaelt1/stream-fusion.git for what it's worth.